# Portable Javascript Application with String to File Output

Tags: javascript, package, portability

I am using Javascript wrapped in HTML to simplify the task of one of my students. Her task is to create a text file for a research project, which will act as a configuration file for the analysis software.

I decided on Javascript, because I wanted portable, transparent code, with zero dependencies (no libs, no server, no installation), yet a familiar feel from the web that is easy to get started with. However, client side Javascript appears to have its limits when it comes to handling file output.

There are multiple questions and answers on Stackoverflow that address the issue by appealing to server-side solutions, external dependencies, and the newer HTML5 download element.

I have considered if I should use a complementary script or batch file that reads the output, but I am not sure about how to best implement such a layer. The file is complex to generate and this is achieved using form elements.

Another idea would be to package the script as an executable. For example, a browser could be called from Java, or the HTML/JS could be converted somehow. Perhaps there is a wrapper that I am not familiar with.

This is one of those side projects that is fast to code and so I would assume that there is a go-to solution among programmers for this type of problem. On the one hand, this is a packaging problem. On the other hand, it is about some of the limitations with Javascript for projects that run without a server backbone.

How can I deliver a no-bells-and-whistles Javascript application that is local only and capable of handling file I/O?

Comment: You might consider something like [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). If you want it to run in a standard browser though, you will not be able to do direct file I/O without some kind of server.

Comment: Blob, createObjectURL and download attribute

Comment: @MikeC Re: Electron. Great concept and useful, but large overhead.

Comment: @noumenal Then you'll either have to write your own Node.js server and bundle that up or write your program in a different language. Browser-side Javascript can't give you what you need so you need a server element. Electron can act as that server and give you a decent way of working with it but if that's a no go, you're out of options in the world of JavaScript, at least as your main host language.